# Comparing all properties of an object using expression trees

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees, dynamic-method

I'm trying to write a simple generator that uses an expression tree to dynamically generate a method that compares all properties of an instance of a type to the properties of another instance of that type. This works fine for most properties, like `int` an `string`, but fails for `DateTime?` (and presumably other nullable value types).

The method:

```
static Delegate GenerateComparer(Type type)
{
  var left = Expression.Parameter(type, "left");
  var right = Expression.Parameter(type, "right");

  Expression result = null;

  foreach (var p in type.GetProperties())
  {
    var leftProperty = Expression.Property(left, p.Name);
    var rightProperty = Expression.Property(right, p.Name);

    var equals = p.PropertyType.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { p.PropertyType });

    var callEqualsOnLeft = Expression.Call(leftProperty, equals, rightProperty);

    result = result != null ? (Expression)Expression.And(result, callEqualsOnLeft) : (Expression)callEqualsOnLeft;
  }

  var method = Expression.Lambda(result, left, right).Compile();

  return method;

}
```

On a `DateTime?` property it fails with:

> Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'

OK, so it finds an overload of `Equals` that expects `object`. So why can't I pass a `DateTime?` into that, as it's convertible to `object`? If I look at `Nullable<T>`, it indeed has an override of `Equals(object o)`.

**PS**: I realize that this isn't a proper generator yet as it can't deal with `null` values, but I'll get to that :)

**UPDATE**: Iraklis' answer did work for this particular problem, but in the end I went for a much simpler approach that I think suffices: just use `Expression.Equal`. I think that covers 99% of my cases (not sure if it can handle overriding `Equals` without overriding `==`, but that's OK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might work if you check that the types are nullable with this code:

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)){}
```

The code sample is from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/806ba860-705a-4076-aaf4-ff25a2725c73/)
And if they are Nullable then you can call

```
Nullable.Equals<T>(T? n1, T? n2);
```

Comment: Thanks, that method solved my problem, but in the end I went for a different approach altogether.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web for something I can use, I decided to implement it myself as well. I did not use expression trees. Instead I use reflection to scan all the properties and use `ToString()` to compare them. If the property is a collection, it will compare every element in the collection for equality.

Here is the code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

namespace Utils
{
    public class PropertyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> allProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach(PropertyInfo pi in allProperties)
            {
                if (pi.GetCustomAttributes<EqualityIrrelevantAttribute>().Any())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                object xProp = pi.GetValue(x);
                object yProp = pi.GetValue(y);

                if ((xProp == null) && (yProp == null))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if ((xProp == null) || (yProp == null))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (xProp is ICollection)
                {
                    if (!CollectionsEqual(xProp as ICollection, yProp as ICollection))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if (xProp.ToString() != yProp.ToString())
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        bool CollectionsEqual(ICollection left, ICollection right)
        {
            IEnumerator leftEnumerator = left.GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator rightEnumerator = right.GetEnumerator();

            bool leftAdvanced = leftEnumerator.MoveNext();
            bool rightAdvanced = rightEnumerator.MoveNext();

            if ((leftAdvanced && !rightAdvanced) || (rightAdvanced && !leftAdvanced))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (!leftAdvanced && !rightAdvanced)
            {
                return true;
            }

            bool compareByClass = false;
            object comparer = null;
            MethodInfo equalsMethod = null;

            // Inspect type first
            object peek = leftEnumerator.Current;
            Type valuesType = peek.GetType();
            if (valuesType.IsClass)
            {
                compareByClass = true;
                Type comparerType = typeof(PropertyComparer<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { valuesType });
                equalsMethod = comparerType.GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { valuesType, valuesType });
                comparer = Activator.CreateInstance(comparerType);
            }


            leftEnumerator.Reset();
            rightEnumerator.Reset();

            while (true)
            {
                leftAdvanced = leftEnumerator.MoveNext();
                rightAdvanced = rightEnumerator.MoveNext();

                if ((leftAdvanced && !rightAdvanced) || (rightAdvanced && !leftAdvanced))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (!leftAdvanced && !rightAdvanced)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                object leftValue = leftEnumerator.Current;
                object rightValue = rightEnumerator.Current;

                if (compareByClass)
                {
                    bool result = (bool)equalsMethod.Invoke(comparer, new object[] { leftValue, rightValue });
                    if (!result)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (leftEnumerator.Current.ToString() != rightEnumerator.Current.ToString())
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // Continue looping
            }
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

If a property of a class is itself a class, then it will create a new comparer that can compare properties of that class. You can also optionally mark particular properties to be excluded from comparision using the `EqualityIrrelevantAttribute`. It works really well for me, I hope others find it useful.